# Lazy Loading UICollectionView Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, lazy-evaluation, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have a `collectionView` which uses `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. It has `150 Sections` and each section can have a `random number of items (up to 30)` depending what comes back from the `API`.

I've been trying to lazy load each section using the `prefetch` API - specifically `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])`.

I'm reloading each section once the data is received using `collectionView.reloadSections(at: [...])` but when I scroll up and down whilst each section is loading, it's very choppy and slow. I've also dispatched the reload on the main thread and have tried using `OperationQueue`.

I've also even tried using the `DiffableDataSource` API but its still slow.

What is the correct way to reload sections, when scrolling and lazy loading, whilst maintaining a smooth scroll experience?

Code Below:

```swift
class View: UIView {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // Reload section once API returns data
    func reloadCell(at index: Int) {
        self.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: index))
    }
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) in
            ...
            return section
        }
        return layout
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension ScheduleView: UICollectionViewDelegate,
                        UICollectionViewDataSource,
                        UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
                        UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    
    // Trigger API for sections
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            dataSource?.willPresentCell(atIndex: indexPath.section)
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource?.numberOfObjects(for: section) ?? 0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 150
    }
}
```

Comment: Either of those approaches (pre fetching or diffable data source) are possible solutions.  Diffable data source is the newest approach and probably what I would use.   It is also important that you provide  reasonable "placeholder" content and layout information so that the collection view doesn't experience drastic layout changes when you update it. You need to [edit] your question to show relevant code.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, have updated the question with the code. The collectionView starts with placeholders for each section. So 150 rows with one item in each saying `Loading...`

Comment: I notice that you have a method called `reloadCell` that reloads a section.  Do you actually call this once of each cell or is it only called once per section?

Comment: Yep exactly. I call this once per section @Paulw11 which I think is why its very choppy when I scroll up and down. This is called once the section has its data from the API. But I'm not sure how to get around this choppiness